# Dataflow apply window function to side output

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a flow where I read messages from pub/sub and apply a windowing function. Currently this job is duplicated in order to apply two different windows to the same data.

```
pipeline.apply("Read PubSub messages",
                    PubsubIO.
                            readStrings().
                            fromSubscription(pubsubSub))

            .apply("Convert to DeviceActivity",
                    ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, KV<String, DeviceActivity>>() {

                        @Override
                        public Duration getAllowedTimestampSkew() {
                            return new Duration(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                        }

                        @ProcessElement
                        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                            String message = c.element();
                            DeviceActivity deviceActivity;

                            try {
                                deviceActivity = new Gson().fromJson(message, DeviceActivity.class);
                            } catch (Exception e2) {
                                LOG.error("Failed to convert to deviceActivity. Message payload was " + message, e2);
                                return;
                            }

                            // use timestamp from payload
                            Long timeInNanoSeconds = deviceActivity.getNanosSinceEpoch();
                            Instant timestamp = ClockUtil.fromNanos(timeInNanoSeconds);
                            long millis = timestamp.toEpochMilli();

                            c.outputWithTimestamp(new TupleTag<>("30sec"), KV.of(sourceId, data), new org.joda.time.Instant(millis));
                            c.outputWithTimestamp(new TupleTag<>("10min"), KV.of(sourceId, data), new org.joda.time.Instant(millis));
                        }
                    }))

            .apply("Apply fixed window", window)
```

Is it possible to output two tags "10sec" and "10min" from the "Convert to DeviceActivity" step and apply different windows to the output depending on the tag?

The code above is already supposed to output two tags, but I am struggling to implement the next step

Comment: Is your question about applying different windows to the output depending on the tag?